# Angular UI Bootstrap progress bar - how to calculate "value" attribute with expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use UI bootstrap progressbar inside a table to give a visual representation of some statistics.  The stats are percentages so it should work quite nicely, i.e. the higher the percentage the longer the bar.

I need to calculate the value with an expression, so I'm creating the progressbar element like so inside the table column:

```
<uib-progressbar type="info" value="{{ ((statValue / total) * 100) }}"></uib-progressbar>
```

Just to clarify, that's a simplified example, but the point is I cannot get any kind of expression to work when trying to calculate the value attribute.

It works if I give the attribute a different name and it works if I create a "value" attribute on any other type of element (e.g. a div).  It just does not seem to work for the value attribute on the uib-progressbar element, which is exactly where I need it!

The error I get in the browser console is:

"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ ((statValue / total) * 100) }}] starting at [{ ((statValue / total) * 100) }}]."

I'm using angularjs 1.4.9 and angular-ui-bootstrap 1.1.2.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` attribute should not be using interpolation `{{}}` inside value attribute, you could directly get scope variable values in it, like other directive of angular does `ng-click`, `ng-if`, etc.

```
<uib-progressbar type="info" value="((statValue / total) * 100)"></uib-progressbar>
```

[**Sample Here**](http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/cvxuJ)

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn I already tried it that way but clearly whatever I did wasn't quite right!